Ubuntu 22.04 : Laptop crashes after sleep, Lenovo P51
I have recently upgraded my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad P51) to Ubuntu 22.04.
Everything seems to be working correctly except the sleeping/waking up. Triggered by closing and re-opening the lid.
I read many similar posts with different solutions and none have worked. This includes:

Changing from Wayland to Xorg (Note that I can not go back to Wayland even after modifying /etc/gdm3/custom.conf"
Updating the firmware
Removing the Security Chip in the BIOS

Help!
Below I have attached the result from:
journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-0.1day' 


jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 systemd-logind[1119]: Suspending...
jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 audit[1083]: USER_AVC pid=1083 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.14" mask="receive" pid=5994 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1119 peer_label="unconfined"
exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1718117588.864:76): pid=1083 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.14" mask="receive" pid=5994 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1119 peer_label="unconfined"
exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 ModemManager[1296]:   [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 NetworkManager[1086]:   [1718117588.8711] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 NetworkManager[1086]:   [1718117588.8712] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 NetworkManager[1086]:   [1718117588.9514] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 NetworkManager[1086]:   [1718117588.9517] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
jun 11 16:53:08 ThinkPad-P51 NetworkManager[1086]:   [1718117588.9520] device (wlp4s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jun 11 16:53:09 ThinkPad-P51 NetworkManager[1086]:   [1718117589.1397] device (wlp4s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jun 11 16:53:09 ThinkPad-P51 NetworkManager[1086]:   [1718117589.1453] device (wlp4s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jun 11 16:53:12 ThinkPad-P51 systemd1: Reached target Sleep.
jun 11 16:53:12 ThinkPad-P51 systemd1: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
jun 11 16:53:12 ThinkPad-P51 suspend[23771]: nvidia-suspend.service
jun 11 16:53:12 ThinkPad-P51 logger[23771]: <13>Jun 11 16:53:12 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
jun 11 16:53:12 ThinkPad-P51 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2865]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
jun 11 16:53:12 ThinkPad-P51 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2865]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 23773 Comm: nvidia-sleep.sh Tainted: P           OE      6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 kernel:  uvm_suspend+0xa6/0x1f0 [nvidia_uvm]
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 kernel:  uvm_suspend_entry+0x85/0xa0 [nvidia_uvm]
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 kernel:  nv_uvm_suspend+0x2e/0x50 [nvidia]
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 kernel:  nv_procfs_write_suspend+0x106/0x1c0 [nvidia]
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: note: nvidia-sleep.sh[23773] exited with irqs disabled
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: note: nvidia-sleep.sh[23773] exited with preempt_count 1
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 systemd1: nvidia-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 systemd1: nvidia-suspend.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 systemd1: Failed to start NVIDIA system suspend actions.
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 systemd1: Starting System Suspend...
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 systemd-sleep[23793]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/displaylink.sh: line 7: /tmp/PmMessagesPort_out: No such file or directory
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 systemd-sleep[23789]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
jun 11 16:53:13 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
jun 11 16:53:56 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
jun 11 16:53:56 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
jun 11 16:53:56 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
jun 11 16:53:56 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
jun 11 16:53:56 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: PM: suspend exit
jun 11 16:53:56 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep
jun 11 16:53:53 ThinkPad-P51 systemd-sleep[23789]: System returned from sleep state.
-- Boot 4f544efaecd14fb881abb83437bb83af --
jun 11 16:54:35 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0
jun 11 16:54:35 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SLPB]
jun 11 16:54:35 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: ata4.00: Features: Trust Dev-Sleep NCQ-sndrcv
jun 11 16:54:35 ThinkPad-P51 kernel: ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep
jun 11 16:54:43 ThinkPad-P51 systemd-logind[1035]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Sleep Button)

Screenshot

Downgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 20.04 "solved" the issue
